# Translating "I will be called Thomas." into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, christianity

In relation to the first words said by a pope when he is elected, would it be right to say that if he chose "Thomas" then the translation of the above is:

"Vocabor Thomas" Or is it "Vocabor Thoma"?

Also, would "I will be called God" be:

"Vocabor Deus"?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the conventional [first words of a Pope](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-pope-succession-text/new-pope-franciss-first-words-after-election-idUSBRE92C19Y20130313) are, but the traditional *announcement* of a new Pope goes like this:

> *Annuntio vobis gaudium magnum: Habemus Papam, eminentissimum ac reverendissimum Dominum, Dominum Georgium Marium Sanctæ Romanæ Ecclesiæ Cardinalem Bergoglio, **qui sibi nomen imposuit Franciscum**.*
>
> I announce a great joy to all of you: we have a Pope, the most eminent and reverend lord, Lord Jorge Mario Bergoglio, Cardinal of the Holy Roman Church, **who took for himself the name Francis**.

Note that some Popes use the accusative and some use the genitive for the name at the end of the announcement; Francis chose the accusative.

If you want to use this phrasing, you would say ***mihi nomen impono Thomae*** (or accusative ***Thoman/Thomam***): "I take for myself the name [of] Thomas".

EDIT: As brianpck points out, the accusative is *Thoman* in Greek and in earlier Latin, but *Thomam* in later Latin.

Comment: Note that in Christian Latin the declension of "Thomas" is Latinized, so the accusative is "Thomam," e.g. [Luke 6:15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lucas+6%3A15&version=VULGATE)

Answer (score 1):

Passive forms of *vocare* go with nominative, not vocative.
For example, in *Pro S. Roscio Amerino* Cicero writes:
*iste qui adest Magnus vocatur*.

Therefore, you would say *vocabor Thomas* and *vocabor Deus*.